# Flask SQLAlchely UPDATE instead of INSERT

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am following a tutorial series from Corey Schafer for making a Flask Web App, but I'm doing something wrong. So when it comes to making a new post from a user to the database it writes in the database with the data from the form, but when I try to add another post from the **same** user I get the error:

```
[SQL: UPDATE post SET user_id=? WHERE post.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, 1)]
```

I have this in my `models.py` that should not let the user_id be `None`:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Login route:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            flash(f'Success.', category='success')
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Unsuccessful!', category='danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Log In', form=form)
```

This is the route for the add new post:

```
@app.route('/post/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_product():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(name=form.name.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Created!', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('new.html', title='Add Post', form=form, legend='New Post')
```

And this is the form:

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = StringField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

In the videos he makes a new post but from another user account. How can I escape that?

The whole error is this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:34] "POST /post/new HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 716, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: post.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\blog\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\store\routes.py", line 101, in new_product
    db.session.commit()
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit

  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1423, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3255, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3395, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3355, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 453, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 627, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 234, in save_obj
    _emit_update_statements(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 998, in _emit_update_statements
    c = connection._execute_20(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1520, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 313, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1389, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1748, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1929, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "D:\Python\HTML\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 716, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: post.user_id
[SQL: UPDATE post SET user_id=? WHERE post.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:34] "GET /product/new?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:34] "GET /product/new?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:34] "GET /product/new?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:35] "GET /product/new?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:35] "GET /product/new?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 15:00:35] "GET /product/new?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**SOLUTION**: I messed the imports in my `forms.py`, it was like this:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from store.models import User
from flask_login import current_user
```

It had to be remade to this:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from store.models import User
```

Comment: Does current_user.is_authenticated?

Comment: Does it what? It is in my `login` route.

Comment: I mean is the user actually logged in? See checking in `register` and `login` routes. Also, for your post you need just user_id so no reason to pass all object, just pass current_user.id.

Comment: Are you sure that's the same route that generate this error message? Make some debug, add some print in the code to be sure. It's look like it's the PUT who is called not the POST

Comment: @Michael Yes it breaks on `db.session.commit` when I'm in the console all of the values are from the form and the `user_id` is `None`. But why it doesn't happen when the user makes the first post too?

Comment: Can you give the whole error message from console?

Comment: Is `current_user` in the session? What does `current_user in db.session` display?

Comment: Hello @IljaEverilä when I try to see the value of `current_user` I get `None`. It's strange that this happens after a first post is submitted. **Edited** The vaue is none at the time of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED: thanks to @IljaEverilä, I was wrong, `backref` can be used for assignment, not only for retrieving. My answer fixed author's problem, but my comment about mistake in tutorial's code is incorrect and actual problem is in another place. For more info about `backref` (with examples for assignement - [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html))**

<s>I put it there because looks like the code in mentioned tutorial has a mistake.</s>

The problem is that your don't pass any `user_id`, but you pass `author`. I checked the code from this tutorial and noticed that `author` field exists in Django model, not Flask. So just replace `author=current_user` with `user_id=current_user.id` and it should work

Comment: Yes thank you, this works, but `author` is backref in the `user` model as seen [here](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/Flask_Blog/05-Package-Structure/flaskblog/models.py)

Comment: Yes, but `backref` is a property tha used to get a related object, not to set it

Comment: Thank you. This is useful info.

Comment: No, `relationship` backref is for creating the mirror `relationship` property at the other end, and usually should support assignments as well. "backref is a property tha used to get a related object, not to set it" is false.

Comment: For details, please read the documents: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html

Comment: @IljaEverilä, you are right, thank you for correcting, I updated my answer